# Working with PayPal HERE and PayPal API

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I am trying to use the PayPal Here Sideloader (C# web application). I am getting unexpected results where the Application doesn't always return to my web application in Safari (iPad). Also, it opens a new tab every time. So I decided to use IPN to handle processing after the purchase.

But while using PayPal HERE, I noticed that **check** and **cash** transactions are not calling my IPN Url. I tried to search transactions using the REST API and I don't even see them. Credit card and Apple pay transactions work fine. So my question is two fold.

1. After speaking to someone at PayPal who might or might not know what they are talking about said something to the effect of, 'those transactions aren't supported'.  I don't necessarily believe that because if I have the Invoice Id (INV2-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX) I can use the REST API to get what I need. Was the person correct, or has anyone else done this before?
2. What if I have my custom Order Id (see image), how can I get the Invoice Id?
   (I've looked at the Invoicing API (REST) and TransactionSearch (NVP) and neither of these return information about the transaction. [image: paypal receipt page on my account]

Comment: I figured it out. It looks like this is the API I needed to use: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hereapi/merchant/v1/invoices

Answer (score 0):

After feeling like I have searched the ENTIRE internet, I saw that the documentation for the iOS and Andriod SDK mentioned the URL for the PayPal Here API.

That url (for production) is https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hereapi/merchant/v1

I just happen to add '/invoices/' to it and got an authentication error. Once I was able to authenticate, I see that this returns a list of all 'invoices' processed in PayPal Here. You'll need to connect using OAuth2, but the list is what I needed to filter based on order ID.